# getting [NSURL cachePolicy]: unrecognized selector sent to instance during downloading an image,AFNetworking

Tags: objective-c, ios, afnetworking

My purpose is trying to get the size of the downloaded image via the successful block like below:

```
[imageView setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURL URLWithString:((ObjectA*)obj[indexPath.row]).imageUrl]
                placeholderImage:nil
                         success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
                            CGFloat imageHeight = image.size.height;
                            CGFloat imageWidth = image.size.width;
                            NSLog(@"width of image is %f",imageWidth);
                            NSLog(@"height of image is %f",imageHeight);
                        }
                        failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                            ;
                        }  ];
```

However, I am getting a crash with shown error like below :

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSURL cachePolicy]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1edb9e70'
```

Does anybody know the reason for this error. Please help if you have any ideas

Comment: A little bit of debug? I'm pretty sure it's not the object that you think it is.

Comment: `[NSURL cachePolicy]` From where this is getting called?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The error is telling you that `cachePolicy` (which is an `NSURLRequest` method) is being called on an `NSURL` object.

The problem is that you are passing in an `NSURL` object as the first parameter instead of an `NSURLRequest` object. (I'm not familiar with this 3rd party API, but the documentation appears to be [here](http://engineering.gowalla.com/AFNetworking/Categories/UIImageView%28AFNetworking%29.html#//api/name/setImageWithURLRequest%3aplaceholderImage%3asuccess%3afailure%3a))

Answer (score 12):

Issue is with this code:

```
[imageView setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURL URLWithString:((ObjectA*)obj[indexPath.row]).imageUrl]
```

The parameter of `setImageWithURLRequest:` is `NSURLRequest`, you are passing `NSURL`. That's why it is crashing.

Change it to:

```
[imageViewsetImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:((ObjectA*)obj[indexPath.row]).imageUrl]]
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess the problem is in the first line

```
[imageView setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl]
```

`setImageWithURLRequest` from the signature looks like expecting a "**URLRequest**" whereas you are passing a **URL**.

So create a `URLRequest` with the `URL` and pass it and see if it is working